# Can anyone suggest a big dataset for the purpose of regression?

Tags: data-request, big-data

I am working on a regression model.I need a big dataset for this purpose.
I have already worked with the famous Airlines dataset(http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/) and the million song dataset (http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/) .I want another dataset to gain deeper insights into the research problem.
Most of the datasets which I found are not so big in UCI repository.

Can anyone suggest a source for this purpose?

Comment: How big does it have to be? Any other requirement, on the topic, the types of variables, etc. ?

Comment: @PeterSmith ,I need atleast one million records.The more the better.It will be good if number of categorial variables are less.The more the continuous variables,better it will be for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

At least a million records you say? I know of a data set that could fit the bill.

The 2013 ACS 5-Year PUMS has a record of 7,300,520 [households](ftp://ftp.census.gov/acs2013_5yr/pums/csv_hus.zip) (which represents 6,671,272 housing units and 629,248 group quarters units) and 14,988,864 [persons](ftp://ftp.census.gov/acs2013_5yr/pums/csv_pus.zip). It is a nationally-representative social survey for the United States.

Comment: Well.thanks for sharing it ,but when I open it ,it has lot of categorial variables and it shows it to be top-coded.

Comment: Fair enough. It is your choice to decide how useful it is to you. I only bring it to your attention.